# ArrayList proper use?

Tags: java, android

Have a question.. I have a list of mp3 filenames
to add a new file name use:

```
musicList.add(new Mp3(id, filename));
```

now I wanted to create a array containing this lists

```
 private static final int LIST_COUNT = 8;
 public static List<List<Mp3>> musicLists = new ArrayList<List<Mp3>>(LIST_COUNT);

private void parseMus(){
     musicLists = new ArrayList<List<Mp3>>(LIST_COUNT);
     ...
    //gettin mp3 list id,filename, length
    ...
    musicLists.get(listNr).add(new Mp3(id,filename,length));
...
}
```

but it gives me errors:

```
     03-15 21:01:36.030: E/AndroidRuntime(3393): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 0
```

---

Second quwestion!
now I edited code and have no errors... BUT now what i get is that all list is filled with same lists.. so when i try to see:

```
        for(int i =0; i< Settings.musicLists.size();i++){
        if(D)Log.e("visio added","MP3 file muslist nr="+i+"= "+Settings.musicLists.get(i)); 
    }
```

I get 8 identical rows shown... what I do wrong?

Comment: are you sure that you want a list of lists containing Mp3 Objects?

Comment: a could make 8 lists.. but think that ArrayList would be better and easyer to use...

Comment: it says Invalid index 4, size is 0 .. while I am creating a new ArrayList with LIST_COUNT =8..

Comment: Yes but you're not putting anything into that first arrayList so it's size is 0 (with a capacity of 8)

Comment: I am bit confused... 
To add after `for (i=0;i<LIST_COUN;i++) musicLists.add(foo)`  when i put `musicLists.get(listNr).add(new Mp3(id,filename,length));` it should put it in the list in listNr ... or Im I understanding it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As VeeArr said you need to fill the list with lists before you can get the lists.

```
// this creates an empty list of initial capacity 8
musicLists = new ArrayList<List<Mp3>>(8);
//  musicList.size() is still 0
// we can add as much items as we want, the list will dynamically grow.
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    List<Mp3> emptySubList = new ArrayList<Mp3>();
    // emptySubList.size() is 0 each as well.
    musicList.add(emptySubList);
}
//  musicList.size() is 8 now.

// do your stuff...
musicLists.get(listNr).add(new Mp3(id,filename,length));
```

The initial capacity you can specify for an `ArrayList` is just a way to improve memory consumption.

`ArrayList`s can dynamically grow unlike `array[]`s. They do that by internally keeping an `array[]` where the data you put in your `ArrayList` is actually stored. If the size they need gets bigger than the `array[]` can hold they create a bigger `array[]` and copy the content to that new version (afaik the size is always doubled).

Thats nice because you don't need to worry about doing that yourself. But copying arrays is expensive. Therefore you can define an initial size to hint your `ArrayList` that it should expect a certain number of elements. It's usually fine if you don't give an initially capacity unless you really know how much items you need.

Comment: Second quwestion! now I edited code and have no errors... BUT now what i get is that all list is filled with same lists.. so when i try to see:
`for(int i =0; i< Settings.musicLists.size();i++){
        if(D)Log.e("musiclist added","MP3 file muslist nr="+i+"= "+Settings.musicLists.get(i)); 
    }` I get 8 identical rows shown... what I do wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`musicLists = new ArrayList<List<Mp3>>(LIST_COUNT);`

You seem to think that this line creates a list of 8 lists. However, what it really does is to create an empty list of lists with initial capacity 8. That is, it doesn't actually populate any lists into `musicLists`.

In order for this you do what you expect it to, you need to initialize `musicLists` and then use `musicLists.add(foo)` to add 8 `List<Mp3>` objects to it.

Comment: you mean I have to
   for(int i = 0; <8;i++) musicList.add(foo);
??

Comment: Or: for (int i =0; i < LIST_COUNT; i++)

Comment: now I get 
    

     03-15 21:24:57.060: E/AndroidRuntime(4397): java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Because nothing is in your original list. Unless you're populating it outside of the code you've posted?